# Need some javascript/jquery horizontal Time Line bar example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i m trying to build a horizontal timeline like this:

http://w3blog.fr/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/timeline-1920x1080.jpg

Event's details(icon with line on picture) won't be shown on page load.On every event(milestone)'s click, smooth animation with thin line and icon (that inside of a circle)  will occur and shows details of event.Data will be fetch from server and it will be as hh:mm format.All events will have different icons and There will be  one initial value.
I saw some similar demo but they have limited options and customization like this:

http://samuelrouse.com/jqTimeline/

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-jQuery-Timeline-Plugin-jqtimeline/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very good JS library for visualizing timelines based on GWT is Chap-links-libary.

It is quite flexible, you can choose your create your own layout and use your own CSS/HTML in each individual event.

Check it [here](http://visjs.org/timeline_examples.html)

Comment: Thanks.It looks like that has every options i need.

Comment: Good suggestion, updated url:  http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/

Answer (score 0):

well this is one of my favorites when it comes to vertical timeline example , since its simple and easy to use.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/tag/timeline/‎

[image: Vertical TimeLine]

Comment: The OP wants a horizontal timeline

Comment: Ahhhh, thats a bummer ;) but logically speaking a timeline looks lot better vertically , as we have so many live examples to prove so